# Bootstrap 4 выровнять кнопку вертикально?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

```
<div class="row bg-light" style="height:5em">
    <div class="col h-75 bg-info">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Read the info</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как в Bootrstrap 4 выровнять вертикально по центру кнопку внутри .col?

На align-self-center кнопка не реагирует, vertical-align: middle; тоже без результатно. Пару дней осваиваю bootstrap 4 буду рад любым советам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Колонке задаёте класс d-flex, а кнопке - align-self-center:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row bg-light" style="height:5em">
    <div class="col h-75 bg-info d-flex">
        <button class="btn btn-danger align-self-center">Read the info</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

А вообще есть клёвая шпаргалка по классам bootstrap 4 с интерактивными примерами:
https://bootstrap-4.ru/articles/cheatsheet/

Comment: Работает спасибо, и отдельная благодарность за ссылку с примерами

Comment: @Cepesh16, рад помочь :)